Broken build result with latest Monogame
I am happy to see that a new version of Monogame has been released recently.
I updated the references for my project and unfortunately the build result is no longer executable just showing the following error on Windows Event Viewer:
Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: Game.exe
Path: C:\Path\To\Publish\Game.exe
Message: The required library C:\Path\To\Publish\hostfxr.dll does not support single-file apps.
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

The problem appears to occur if the project file contains any of the following:

<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>

The following is the smallest project file I tried:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <!-- <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile> -->
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <!-- <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> -->
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <!-- <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun> -->
    <TieredCompilation>false</TieredCompilation>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Framework.WindowsDX" Version="3.8.2.1105" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

With:

Visual Studio 2022(17.11.3)
Monogame 3.8.2.1105

Although it does not appear to be strictly a Monogame issue.
But referencing a package that is referenced by a Monogame project file instead of Monogame itself does not cause this problem; referencing Monogame does.
Version 3.8.1.303 did not have this problem.
I would like the game to be built as a single file with ReadyToRun enabled. I also do not like extra files for other platforms as it is enough to run on Windows(x64).

as per the error message, it seems hostfxr.dll doesn't support this, .NET runtime must be installed on the client. What is this library ?

This error occurs in the development environment and the appropriate NET runtime is installed.
It may be due to a bug or limitation in the publishing process, I think.
